# Indoor positioning app

Tags: java, android

for a university project I want to create an indoor positioning app for android. I want to use step detection for positioning in a specific university building.

When you start the app you should tell your position via tap in a map of the building. But there's the problem, I discovered the Google Maps indoor sdk, but that's not what i really need.

Anyone an idea how to create the indoor map or which sdk I should chose?

Comment: You're going to figure out a user's position based on just an initial location and a step counter? How do you know the direction...? What comes to a map, why not just use floorplan images and a little bit of imagination without any "SDK".

Comment: use FusedLocation you can get user location even indoor, it uses, GPS, wifi, data, etc to get user location from the name "fused"